# Take Mean of Multiple Multidimensional array in a dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a dictionary of 50(days) multidimensional arrays of gridded (lat/lon) data of precipitation. Each array is of size (88, 40). How can I compute the mean of all 50 arrays, and get the result in the same dimension of (88, 40)? i.e. need to take mean at same lat/lon point over all the 50 days.

It works for few days if I give Dictionary name with keys in the following code:

```
np.nanmean((arraysDict['ppt_subset0'], arraysDict['ppt_subset1']), axis =0)
```

These are the keys of my dictionary arraysDict
['ppt_subset0',
 'ppt_subset1',
 ...
 'ppt_subset49']

But I do not know how to do it for all 50 days, except typing "arraysDict['ppt_subset0']", 50 times in my code of all dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all of the values of the dict with `.values()`:

```
np.nanmean(list(arraysDict.values()), axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can convert it to a one giant 3-dimensional numpy array and then compute the mean:

```
arr = np.array(list(arraysDict.values()))
mean = arr.mean(axes=0)
```

Beware though that `arr` won't necessarily contain the subarrays (or days) in order.

Comment: Not really a concern for the mean.